# How can I find an approximation for eigenvalues for an ellipse?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\Omega$ be an ellipse with major and minor semi-axis $a$ and $b$. How can I find the upper and lower bounds for the Dirichlet problem

$\nabla^2\chi=\lambda \chi$ in $\Omega$

$\chi|_{\partial\Omega}=0$

on $\Omega$ using the Rayleigh-Ritz variational principle?

$\lambda_1=inf \frac{(\chi,\nabla^2\chi)}{(\chi,\chi)}$

The first idea I have it's to calculate on a rectangle $\Omega '$ that contains $\Omega$, and another rectangle $\Omega''$ that is contained inside $\Omega$, but I'm not sure if it is a good idea.

Comment: Can you go about this using separation of variables? That is, choose an elliptical coordinate system and write down the appropriate Laplacian operator. Then postulate that $\chi$ is the product of a radial and angular components, and you break the problem into two (three?) parts.

Comment: Found this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.07768.pdf

Comment: Perhaps useful: [elliptic coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_coordinate_system)